# Excel: How to get last result from above

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a problem that is described in the picture below. Until today, I have done manual changes to the formula and that will take time if I have massive data.

Anyone can help? I want to fix B7 and the next cell if I found another gap.

This is what i use:
[image: This is what i use]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1377467/edit) to 1) add the formula you are currently using (as text) 2) let us know exactly what the expected output is

Comment: Can you not remove that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `LOOKUP` formula to find the next non-empty value from above. For example, in row 7, column B (like in your example), enter

```
  =LOOKUP(2,1/(B$1:B6<>""),B$1:B6)
```

This will find the next non-empty value in the area above B7. I have placed the $ characters intentionally for copying the formula down the column.

(detailed explanation of the formular [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell))

If you have several thousands of rows, this may become a little bit slow, since the above formula leads to quadratic run time behaviour. If thats the case, but there is a known limit for the size of your gaps (for example, 2 rows), you can restrict the lookup to this specific number of rows, like

```
  =LOOKUP(2,1/(B4:B6<>""),B4:B6)
```

This checks only the three rows above B7 for valid values.

Comment: sorry for slow respond, i will test it now